# Matlab: perform min cut with positive non-integer edge weights

Tags: matlab, graph

I am looking for a library\file to perform a min cut on an undirected graph with positive non-integer edge weights. Any good recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked MATLAB Graph functions:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/mupad/Graph/index.html

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/mupad/Graph/minCut.html

it's not so difficult.